# Logic to update subsequent start and end date times

Tags: c#, algorithm, date, time, logic

Suppose I have a two objects with a **[start DateTime]** and an **[end DateTime]**
If I change the **[start DateTime]** and/or **[end DateTime]** of the 1st object, I want to like to apply that change to the next object's **[start DateTime]** and/or **[end DateTime]**.

What would be the best way to do this without "**The dates overlapping**"?

**NOTE: THE NEXT OBJECT SHOULD HAVE [start DateTime] and [end DateTime] AFTER THE FIRST OBJECT'S [start DateTime] and [end DateTime].**

**UPDATE** THE time difference between each objects start and end time shouldn't change at all.

**Example :** Same date for all objects in this example. Can be different.
OBJECT 1  ->>>  START (07:58)  END (08:28)
OBJECT 2  ->>>  START (08:48)  END (10:30)

When OBJECT 1 is changed to ->> START (07:56)  END (10:46)
OBJECT 2 should change ->> START (after OBJECT 1 END) END (after OBJECT 2 START)

The differnce should be similar as well. For example, we added 2 hrs and 18 minutes to OBJECT 1 END, so OBJECT 2 should ideally have times increased by 2 hrs 18 minutes. Also, we decreased the OBJECT 1 START by 2 minutes. This should ideally be reflected in OBJECT 2 times as wll.

**Current logic :** PSEUDO CODE
What I'm currently doing is,

```
var OBJECT1StartDifference = OBJECT1.OriginalStart - OBJECT1.Start;
var OBJECT1EndDifference = OBJECT1.OriginalEnd - OBJECT1.End;

ForEach(nextObject in ParentObject.where(obj => obj.Order > OBJECT1.order))
{
   if(OBJECT1StartDifference.HasValue)
   {
      nextObject.Start.Add(OBJECT1StartDifference);
   }

   if(OBJECT1EndDifference.HasValue)
   {
      nextObject.End.Add(OBJECT1EndDifference);
   }
}
```

Comment: You should have a "parent" object that stores the two objects in question. That way you can centralize the logic for coordinating the child objects. Ideally, you design a class that encapsulates the objects you're using and methods to synchronize their dates.

Comment: Please provide the actual code you've written and a [mre] of your issue. Afterwards, we can provide some suggestions to achieve the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: I do have a parent object (which has these objects as children. I am trying to create a method for when one of these onject's time is edited, the method calculates the difference between the original and new times, and apply that difference to the next/ subsequent objects in the list, without overlapping the times.

Comment: That's very doable, but you should share the code you've written so far if you want specific advice beyond "design a class that synchronizes the DateTime's of the child objects"

Comment: Set the next object's start DateTime to the previous object's end DateTime. And set the next object's end DateTime to the value of its start DateTime plus one hour.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Thanks! But I don't want to change the users supplied times for OBJECT2 by setting it to the OBJECT1 times + 1 hour. I want the times to consistently increase/decrease by a time difference.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of something that would work.

Instead of calculating the difference between start times and end times, I'm now only calculating the difference between end times for the OBJECT1.

Then I'm applying this difference to OBJECT2 start and end time.

This will keep the OBJECT2 times always after OBJECT1 times and keep the difference between OBJECT2 start and end time the same.

Note: I also have a logic to change the OBJECT1 start time if end time is edited, and end time if start time is edited, to keep the difference between start and end time the same always.

PSEUDO CODE:

```
var deltaObject1EndTime = OBJECT1.EndTime - OBJECT1.PreviousEndTime; 

if(deltaObject1EndTime != o)
{
    foreach(var OBJECT in PARENTOBJECT.Objects.Where(obj => obj.Order > OBJECT1.Order))
    {
        OBJECT.StartTime.Add(deltaObject1EndTime);
        OBJECT.EndTime.Add(deltaObject1EndTime);
    }
}
```